# How to use the displayed value on powerbuilder for computation

Tags: powerbuilder

I just want to ask on how to solve my problem. On my report window, I have 2 computed fields:

1. A field that computes for decimal and I am displaying it to two decimals only (no problem on the display).
2. On my other computed field, I use the result of the first computed field to be multiplied to a certain number. The problem is here, because the value being multiplied is not the value being displayed from the first field. Instead it uses the whole amount.

Scenario:

- 2,055,232.135 is the computed value and id displays 2,055,232.14 which is good.
- But if I multiply it to 9 (2055232.135 * 9), the result is 18,497,089.215 which will be displayed as 18,497,089.22
- The problem is I want that the displayed value (2,055,232.14) to be multiplied to 9 (2055232.14 * 9) which will then results to 18,497,089.26

I only wanted to achieve the 2nd value for the computed field so that if the user computes for it, it will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution can be used in a computed field:

```
String( Truncate( 2055232.135 * 9, 2), "#,##0.00")
```